# Cannot see aliases

Tags: bash, alias

I have my root user and another user testuser. Now in the .bashrc of testuser, there are some aliases like la for ls -a. But when I login to testuser and try running la, it gives me the error: 
 -sh: la: not found

Even when I try to find $HOME, it says Permission denied (?)

This is slowing down my work!! Help!

Comment: `sh` is not `bash`.  Check the login shell setting of `testuser`.

Comment: look at the error message, make sure .bashrc file owned by testuser.

Comment: testuser is owner of .bashrc

Comment: by the way, i am using SSH

Answer (score 4):

The message from the shell begins with `-sh`. This gives two important clues:

- The leading `-` indicates that this is a login shell. By convention, the login program (the program where you type your user name and password, which can be `login`, gdm, sshd, …) starts a shell with the program name set to begin with an extra `-`. This way, the shell knows that it's a login shell and reads `~/.profile` or other session startup file.
- The shell's name is `sh`. So the user's login shell is set to `/bin/sh`, and not to bash. Either `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to bash, or it's some other shell such as dash. When bash is invoked under the name `sh`, it doesn't read its configuration files, only the standard files (`~/.profile` and `/etc/profile` in login shells, nothing in non-login shells), for compatibility. So either way `~/.bashrc` is not read.

If you explicitly invoke bash, it will read `.bashrc`. You'll need to pass the `-t` flag to `ssh` to tell it to open a terminal even though you've specified a command.

```
ssh -t testuser@nameofhost bash
```

You may want to switch the user's login shell to be bash instead of `/bin/sh`. As `testuser`, run the command

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Change the path to `/usr/local/bin/bash` or wherever bash is located. If you invoke `chsh` without arguments, you'll get a menu showing what shells you're allowed to select.

Answer (score -1):

You can check your system wide /etc/bashrc and/or /etc/profile files.
Also you can add something like this to the files:

```
if [ `whoami` == "testuser" ] 
then  
   alias x='echo x' # alias list..
fi
```